# Typescript - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm struggling doing a simple push of value into an array. Here is my code: I'm trying to translate an Angular app but the information are not in the html but in the `ts` file.

```js
export class EventReportModalComponent implements OnInit {
  reasons: Array<string>;
  reasonsKeys = [
    'report.reason.nudity',
    'report.reason.hate-speech',
    'report.reason.violence',
    'report.reason.bullying',
    'report.reason.false-information',
    'report.reason.undesirable-content',
    'report.reason.other',
  ];

  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    let reasons;
    for (let item of this.reasonsKeys) {
      this.translate.get(item).subscribe(res => {
        reasons.push(res);
      });
    }

    this.reasons = reasons;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

I have this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I don't understand how I can achieve that in javascript. Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: You need to initialize reasons with []: `let reasons = []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code.

1. Undefined `reasons`

You have to init `reasons` with an empty array before being able to `push` something into it:
`let reasons = []`;

2. Asynchronous function

`this.translate.get` is asynchronous. So when this is not the right approach.
You should instead dynamically push items to the finaly object.

```
let reasons;
for (let item of this.reasonsKeys) {
  this.translate.get(item).subscribe(res => {
    reasons.push(res);
  });
}

this.reasons = reasons; // reasons is empty, because this.translate.get did not answer yet
```

why not pushing directly in `this.reasons` instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `reasons` variable in the constructor with -

```
let reasons = [];
```

Comment: @Random Oops! Thanks  :)

Answer (score 1):

`translate.get` accepts an array, so you should be able to get the translations in one go:

```js
this.translate.get(this.reasonsKeys).subscribe(res => {
  this.reasons = res;
});
```

Note: If you started to use ngx-translate please be aware that it might not be developed further: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/783